# Using a for loop to find the greatest integer from an array of 5 integers

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;

public class Project5{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Candidate[] candidateList = new Candidate[ARRAY_SIZE]; 
    String name;
    int votes;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter Candidate #" + (i + 1) + " Name: ");
        name = console.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please Enter the number of votes " + name + " Received:    ");
        votes = console.nextInt();
        candidateList[i] = new Candidate(name, votes);
        console.nextLine();
    }

    Candidate winner;
    winner = candidateList[0];
```

This is where i have my issue, i have the for loop counting each of the five Strings i the Array but it doesn't seem to pick the String which has the most votes to be the winner.  I feel like this is rather simple and it is simply flying over my head.

Also is what is the quickest way to simplify this part here?

```
  System.out.print("      Candidate   Votes Recieved  % of Total Votes");

  System.out.print("\n");
  System.out.print("\n");
```

One more thing, is there a way to simply have a code like this but in one format?  So like `{System.out.print(candidateList[i].getCandidateInfo());}`

```
    System.out.print(candidateList[0].getCandidateInfo());
    System.out.print(candidateList[1].getCandidateInfo());
    System.out.print(candidateList[2].getCandidateInfo());
    System.out.print(candidateList[3].getCandidateInfo());
    System.out.print(candidateList[4].getCandidateInfo());

    System.out.print("The winner is: " + winner);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Remove the `else winner = candidateList[0];` statement .

Comment: These are actually 3 questions.

Comment: `what is the quickest way to simplify this part here?` - Simplify in what way? Less code? Better layout? - `is there a way to simply have a code like this but in one format?` - What's the difference or the problem? How about putting the statement into a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Like Berger said "Remove the else winner = candidateList[0];".
2. `System.out.print("      Candidate   Votes Recieved  % of Total Votes\n"\n"");`
3. No. I would override the `toString()` method though in you `Candidate` class, to confirm more to standards. Then call `candidateList[0].toString()`.

Or you could do it in a loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
  System.out.print(candidateList[i].getCandidateInfo());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Everything works perfectly.  Wish i could vote for your comment but I am don't yet have enough reputation.

Comment: Glad it helped! You should be able to accept my answer though, which would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implement Comparable Interface to your Candidate class and implement the

```
public int compareTo(Candidate candidate) {

        int votes = Candidate.getCVotes(); 



        //descending order
        //return votes - this.cVotes;

    }
```

Instead of for loop do

```
Arrays.sort(candidateList)
```

The 0th element after sorting will be the winner.
This way if tomorrow you need to know the 2nd and 3rd position holder you can simply print 1 and 2 indexed element from your candidateList.